# Redirect connections from VPS to IP

Tags: 14.04, networking, iptables, redirect

I'm trying to develop my own "DNS" server using subdomains. Let' say I have this struture:

- VPS server with **Ubuntu**
- VPS server IP: **`1.1.1.1`**
- External computers on: **`2.2.2.2`** and **`3.3.3.3`**
- Subdomain '**mysubdomain1.com**' and '**mysubdomain2.com**' pointing to **`1.1.1.1`**

I want to redirect connections:

- If the connection comes from '**mysubdomain1.com**' redirect to  **`2.2.2.2`**
- If the connection coems from '**mysubdomain2.com**' redirect to **`3.3.3.3`**

Wich is the best approach to do this by my own ? Bind9 ?

- Is possible to know the domain or subdomain of the incoming connection if it isn't on port 80 ?
- Should I configure my vps server IP as the domain DNS ?